# Draw from another method doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms

In this code I'm creating a grid in the `Form1` class and by key values, from the arrow keys, I can move a symbol "@" over the grid, and it works just fine.

If I'm calling the `ComputerPlayer` class the x and y coordinates change like expected (recording to visual studio debugger), but the graphics don't change.

What am I missing?

```
public class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        Text = "Form1";
        Size = new Size(400, 400);
        Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Print);
        CenterToScreen();
    }

    public void Print(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
        int i = 0, j;
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Cursor);

        ...
    }    

    public void Cursor(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Font arialBold = new Font("Arial", 14.0F);
        {
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, ("@"), arialBold,
            new Point(x, y), Color.Red);
        }
    }
}

public class ComputerPlayer : Form1
{
    public void InitiateComputerCursor()
    {        
        if (count-- != 0)
        {
            Paint += new PaintEventHandler(ComputerCursor);
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void ComputerCursor(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        Font arialBold = new Font("Arial", 14.0F);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, ("@"), arialBold,
        new Point(x, y), Color.Red);
    }
}
```

Comment: You likely should not have `Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Cursor);` in the `Print` function, otherwise you will be creating a extra event call every paint event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I got it totally wrong but looking at your code it seems you are inheriting from Form1, this is creating two different instances of Form1 but only one is shown on the screen so changes to ComputerPlayer will not have any visual effect.

May be you could change the code as follows:

```
public class ComputerPlayer
{
    private Form1 _form1;

    public ComputerPlayer(Form1 form) 
    {
         _form1 = form;
    }

    public void InitiateComputerCursor()
    {        
        if (count-- != 0)
        {
            _form.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(ComputerCursor);
            _form.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void ComputerCursor(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        Font arialBold = new Font("Arial", 14.0F);
         //You might need to replace the following line for a method in form1 that have access to TextRenderer
        _form1.TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, ("@"), arialBold,
        new Point(x, y), Color.Red);
    }
}
```

Then whatever you initialize ComputerPlayer in Form1 pass the reference to the constructor:

```
ComputerPlayer computerPlayer = new ComputerPlayer(this);
```